# Cannot move submenu (dropdown menu) under parent menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navbar

I am having problems aligning the dropdown/submenu under *parent* menu. To be clear, I want my submenu to show when I hover over ***Services***. I will post the code and also attach a photo to be clear.

Edit: I have updated the snippet! I think it is alright right now. Thank you!

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background-color: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #2a5298, #1e3c72);
  background-color: linear-gradient(to right, #2a5298, #1e3c72);
  background-color: #1e3c72;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  height: 10vh;
}

.nav-links ul {
  position: absolute;
  /* display: none; */
}

.nav-links li a {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.nav-links li {
  transition: all .6s ease-out;
  border-radius: 40px;
  height: 70%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 18px;
}

.nav-links li:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  height: 60%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #1e3c72;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
  transition: all .6s ease;
  padding: 10px 18px;
}

.nav-links li:hover a {
  color: #1e3c72;
}

.nav-links img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  filter: invert(100%);
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-links li i {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="index.html" id="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Quality Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Auditing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue? the snippet you share is not helping us!

Comment: you added the snippet as answer! which is incorrect, can you edit the same question and delete the answer?

Comment: @Manjuboyz I've tried that but it said that I had the most of my question as code and I had to write more details... So I tried to add it as an answer. But I'll try to edit my question again :).

Comment: Ok, let me do it behalf of you.

Comment: I have updated your code in the question, can you go ahead and delete the answer you posted?

Comment: @Manjuboyz Sure. Thanks for editing my code. I just deleted my answer. Can you review my code one more time and maybe fix the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On limited resource of what you shared, I assume this is what you need?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  height: 30px;
}

nav ul {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}

nav ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="index.html" id="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Quality Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Auditing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: @Jay I have shared my code, you may have to do a little tweak to get it fixed. I am still not able to understand what you need.